# I am unable to upload my iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app got rejected due to following ,

> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs: IOObjectRelease, IOServiceGetMatchingService, _IOServiceMatching.

Then i removed those files in my app. and tried to upload the app but can't able to upload because i am unable to view the build (+) options in iTunes connect.  Eventhough i got email from apple like your app is ready to submit.But can't able to view the build options in iTunes connect I am trying from last 2 days .Please any one help me to do this .

Comment: Did you get email like with subject "iTunes Connect: Version XXX (1.0) for YourAppName has completed processing"?

Comment: Did you manage to upload the build to store? Or still the error is there?

Comment: Yes i got the email"iTunes Connect: Version XXX (1.0) for YourAppName has completed processing"

Comment: In Itunes Connect - > My Apps -> Activity -> and check the status of your app. If you can please share a screenshot of the same here.

Comment: there is nothing in status